# $_SESSION[something] without quotes

Tags: php, sql

Why is this working?

```
$sql= "SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE Name='$_SESSION[Name]'; ";
```

If I put the name inside `$_SESSION` in single `''` or double `""` quotes it's not working, but somehow it does work with no quotes

Comment: Because it will lead to a syntax error. You're already in double quotes.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard PHP [string parsing behaviour](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) (the `"Simple syntax"`). If you want to put quotes around the key you need to enclose the whole variable in `{}` (the `"Complex syntax"`) e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE Name='{$_SESSION["Name"]}'; ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query must be like below

```
$sql= "SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE Name='".$_SESSION['Name']."'; ";
```